# Tensorflow CUDA - CUPTI error: CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nvidia

I use the Tensorflow v 1.14.0. I work on Windows 10. And here is how relevant **environment variables** look in the `PATH`:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\libnvvp
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Users\sinthes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
C:\Users\sinthes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\cuda\bin
```

Maybe also worth to mention, just in case it might be relevant.. I use Sublime Text 3 for development and I do not use Anaconda. I find it a bit cumbersome to make updates on tensorflow in the conda environment so I just use Sublime Text right now. (I was using Anaconda (Spyder) previously but I uninstalled it from my computer.)

Things seem to work fine except with some occasional strange warnings. But one consistent warning I get is the following whenever I run the `fit` function.

```
E tensorflow/core/platform/default/device_tracer.cc:68] CUPTI error: CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
```

And here is how I call the fit function:

```
history = model.fit(x=train_x,
                    y=train_y,
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs=110,
                    verbose=2,
                    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint, reduce_lr_on_plateau],
                    validation_data=(dev_x, dev_y),
                    shuffle=True,
                    class_weight=class_weight,
                    steps_per_epoch=None,
                    validation_steps=None)
```

I just wonder why I see the **`CUPTI Error`** message during the run time? It is only printed out once. Is that something that I need to fix or is it something that can be ignored? This message does not tell anything concrete to me to be able to take any action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what solved "my" problem:

I just replaced my `tensorflow v 1.14` with `tensorflow v 1.13.1`. And no more **CUPTI error** messages. And even some other strange warnings / problems have disappeared. All issues should obviously have specific reasons but Tensorflow (many times) unfortunately does not provide understandable error/warning messages that give a good/fair idea that helps to solve the issue. And I end up spending hours (even days) on such strange problems, that reduces my productivity significantly.

One general learning for me (that might be relevant to share here) is that I should not be in hurry to upgrade my tensorflow installation to the latest version of it. The latest one is almost never stable, whenever I made a try, I ended up spending **significant** amount of time on problems that are caused by tensorflow. Poor documentation and error messages make it very very difficult to work with.

If anyone has a better answer, s/he is more than welcome to share his/her insights on the issue I shared in this question.

Answer (score 11):

Add this in `path` for Windows:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64
```

Comment: Thanks ! This worked great. Now I have the correct message : "Successfully opened dynamic library cupti64_100.dll"

Comment: I also had to run my Python script as an administrator to make this work.

Comment: I don't have this path... Any other alternative?

Comment: Following a couple of pratfalls I just experienced: if you're launching from a command window (for instance if you're using Jupyter Lab), remember to start a new command window in order to load the PATH changes; also, you'll need to run the command window as an administrator. I was having problems getting TensorBoard Profiling to work fully using the Keras callback; it's all good now.

Answer (score 11):

> The NVIDIA® CUDA Profiling Tools Interface (CUPTI) is a dynamic
>   library that enables the creation of profiling and tracing tools that
>   target CUDA applications.

CPUTI seems to have been added by the Tensorflow Developors to allow profiling. You can simply ignore the error if you don't mind the exception or adapt your environment path, so the dynamically linked library (DLL) can be found during execution.

Inside of you CUDA installation directory, there is an `extras\CUPTI\lib64` directory that contains the `cupti64_101.dll` that is trying to be loaded. Adding that directory to your path should resolve the issue, e.g.,

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64;%PATH%
```

N.B. in case you get an [INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES error](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-err-nvgpuctrperm-cupti) next, try to run your program as administrator.

Answer (score 9):

**This answer is for `Ubuntu-16.04`**.

I had this issue when I upgraded to `Tensorflow-1.14` with `Python2.7` and `Python3.6`. I had to add `/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and logout and login. `source ~/.bashrc` didn't help. Note that my `cuda` folder was pointing to `cuda-10.0`.

Answer (score 5):

Ran in to this same issue. This is what fixed it for me incase someone else has a similar  problem fixing this.

*error I received:*

```
function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.
```

- Windows Server 2019
- Tensorflow 2.5
- Cuda 11.2 (**CUDA_PATH** environment variable is set and added to the **PATH** environment variable)
- Cudnn 8.1.0

I had already set `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\extras\CUPTI\lib64` in the **PATH** environment variable but was still receiving the error.

Running `where /r c:\ cupti*.dll` in a cmd prompt found dll's in the `c:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Systems 2020.4.3\target-windows-x64\` directory. Simply adding this directory to the **PATH** environment variable fixed the error.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error when trying to get tensorboard graph, I think it only affects you if you plan to use tensorboard.

I found the solution in this post but it is for linux
https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/6d6c3f23ea057775b72c52817759b25c
I think you need to create a library configuration file for cupti.

Comment: I do need to be able to use tensorboard. Tensorflow is a mess.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what solved "my" problem:

Windows 10, Tensorflow-gpu 2.4

The first issue, was it was unclear about exactly "which" cupti64 version it was trying to load. With that in mind, I did a search for all dll's called cupti*

[image: screen-shot1]

I then copied them all (yeh I know it's hack, but given limited information...) into my

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\extras\CUPTI\lib64

folder (cupti64_2020.1.0.dll was in there already)

[image: screen-shot2]

I then needed to also set the folder permission to get it to work, which was strange as I was running VS as admin

[image: screen-shot3]

Answer (score 0):

I also just ran into this issue, exactly as jreeves.  I solved it exactly following jreeves' method (above). (Thanks to jreeves for his/her work in finding and documenting the solution.)
MY setup:

- Windows 10
- Gpu  Support:       True
- Cuda Support:       True
- TensorFlow:        2.4.1
- Python version:      3.8.8.
- Tensorboard version  2.4.1.
- Cuda 11.1
- Cudnn 8.0.5