# Tensorboard Profiler: Failed to load libcupti (is it installed and accessible?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, tensorboard

I'm trying to analyze my tensorflow application. The training runs well, but I get `Failed to load libcupti (is it installed and accessible?)` if I open the Profile-Tab in Tensorboard.

**My configuration is**:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.7
- Tensorflow 2.6.0
- CUDA Toolkit 11.2
- cuDNN 8.1.1 (installed as [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html) by copying files as described)
- Visual Studio Professional 2019

`CUDA_PATH` is `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2`

**My Path-Variable contains**:

- `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin`
- `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\libnvvp`
- `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\extras\CUPTI\lib64`
- `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include`
- `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Systems 2020.4.3\target-windows-x64`

`conda list` (only relevant packages):

```
cudatoolkit               11.3.1               h59b6b97_2
cudnn                     8.2.1                cuda11.3_0
tensorboard               2.6.0                      py_1
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.0            py39haa95532_0
tensorboard-plugin-profile 2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0
tensorflow                2.6.0           gpu_py39he88c5ba_0
tensorflow-base           2.6.0           gpu_py39hb3da07e_0
tensorflow-datasets       4.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.6.0              pyh7b7c402_0
tensorflow-gpu            2.6.0                h17022bd_0
tensorflow-metadata       1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

I am surprised that Anaconda has installed CUDA Toolkit version 11.3 and cuDNN version 8.2.1.
According to [GPU-configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations) this should be version 11.2 and 8.1. Can this be the problem?

Or has someone an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: See this similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860180/tensorflow-cuda-cupti-error-cupti-could-not-be-loaded-or-symbol-could-not-be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden in the log output of jupyter I found an this error message: `Could not load dynamic library 'cupti64_113.dll': dlerror: cupti64_113.dll not found`
(This log can be found in terminal, where jupyter is running.)

With this error message and [that github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43030#issuecomment-799969225) I was able to solve the problem:
I copied `cupti64_2020.3.0.dll` in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\extras\CUPTI\lib64` and renamed it to `cupti64_113.dll` and now the profiler works.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I would like to determine what the name of the .dll file should be for my installation.  Where did you find the `log output of jupyter` ?

Comment: Are you talking about the log console: `view->show log console`?
I tried copying the file to cupti64_113.dll but it didn't fix the problem.